# Why does my Ngrx store have 2 different states for the same field?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

I'm trying to implement something similar to the [official docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/store#tutorial). I'm using the same actions and reducers as mentioned in the tutorial.

My counter component looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { increment } from '../store/actions';

export class CounterComponent implements OnInit {
  count$: Observable<number>;

  public constructor(private store: Store<{ count: number }>) {
    this.count$ = store.pipe(select('count'));
  }

  public onCounterClick() {
    this.store.dispatch(increment());
  }
}
```

With the following markup

```
<button type="button" (click)="onCounterClick()">
  <span>Count: {{ count$ | async }}</span>
</button>
```

This does work; when I click on the button, the count does increase. However, my problem lies when I have another component trying to update the state.

In my secondary, card component, I have this:

```
export class cardComponent {
  public constructor(private store: Store<{ count: number }>) {

  }

  public onCardClick() {
    this.store.dispatch(increment());
  }
}
```

When I click on the card component, the number increases for only the card -- it doesn't update the count for the counter component. In effect, ngrx is keeping track of two different states, even though I want only a single source of truth. I'm registering the counter in my module `StoreModule.forRoot({ count: counterReducer }),` so, I figured there would only be a single `counter` state. What's wrong here?

Comment: It would be useful to also mention in which module is the `StoreModule` imported and which module(s) declare the `CounterComponent` and the `CardComponent`.

Comment: This should work fine. Does it show 2 different keys in the store?

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu I found the problem and it was related to your comment: I had originally imported `StoreModule` in the same module as the other components. But this is an existing app with many modules, components, etc. So when I moved the `StoreModule` to the top-level module (while keeping the component imports in the same place), the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a common state while initializing the store in both the components.

You may define the state and its initial value in the reducer and export the state from the reducer file, and use it in the following way in the constructors of the components.

`public constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {}`

You can declare the AppState in the `reducer` file as following:

```
export interface AppState{
  count: number
}

const initialState: AppState= {
  count: 0
};
```

This would allow a common reference to your state from both the components

Comment: It would require additional changes as to how the store is declared and how the increment and decrement actions are reduced.
Here is a working example of what I had proposed: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nsbnpg

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet. I found out that the problem was that I imported `StoreModule` in the same module as the other components. I moved the `StoreModule` to the top-level module (while keeping the component imports in the same place), and this fixed my problem. However, I went with your suggestions and added the `AppState` interface.